# Is it legal to bring Jamón Ibérico from Spain into the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, spain

I'm in Spain and I'd love to bring some [Jamón Ibérico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam%C3%B3n_ib%C3%A9rico) back to the states with me.

Is it legal to bring it with me? If so, how much is allowed and under what conditions (sealed, treated, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the [US Embassy in Madrid FAQ](http://madrid.usembassy.gov/citizen-services/faq-spain.html) and the previous experience my wife had past December coming back from Barcelona it is a **no**.

The flights from Spain and especially from Barcelona are almost universally go through agriculture control at US customs (at least the case in JFK and Newark) specifically looking for Jamon.

The only possible exception might be vacuum packed sliced Jamon but again from my wife's experience with agriculture control in Newark I would say it may be a 50/50 proposition at best.

Comment: hmm, might get lucky with some vacuum packs. Same with tulip bulbs from Amsterdam, some stores and manufacturers specialise in packing them in such a way that they're legal for entry into the US (and give you certificates that ascertain that).

Comment: You might.  The security in Newark was basically 2 stage.  First a dog was walking around looking for meats.  At which point a bunch was thrown in the garbage that was at the luggage carousels and another one in the hall.  Then for those lucky enough to pass that you have an XRay machine that will make meats show up in bright red color on the screen.

Comment: Solution: fly to the US with a layover?

Comment: Let me know how it will work out...

Comment: You're talking about whether you could get it through, not whether it is legal to bring it.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t even try the vacuum pack. I read this post, tried, and was confiscated at customs. The answer is a clear no.